# How to use LangChain to store, load, and query Loaders on LlamaHub?

Tags: python, langchain, llama-index, py-langchain, large-language-model

Can loaders on LlamaHub only use LlamaIndex? How can LangChain be used to store, load, and query it?
For example, [Mongo Loader](https://llama-hub-ui.vercel.app/l/mongo).

I saw on LlamaHub that it seems that all the examples use LlamaIndex.
So what can LlamaHub provide for LangChain?

If possible, could you provide me with a specific code example?

Best regards

Comment: You can store and load on langchain itself